# Covariance in an error propagation leading to negative variance

Tags: simulation, covariance, standard-error, monte-carlo, error-propagation

Does it ever make sense that, propagating the error from a set of data, the covariance term being very negative makes the variance go to a negative value (which by itself makes no sense)?

Context:

Let my data set be $t_i$, (i=1,..,N), no errors related with these values since they come from a montecarlo simulation.
Now, the function I want to evaluate is:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=f\Bigg(\overline{t^2},\overline{t}\Bigg)=\overline{t^2}-\overline{t}^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\overline{t}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nt_i\tag{2}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\overline{t^2}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nt^2_i\tag{3}
\end{equation}

let $\sigma_{\overline{t}}^2=\sigma_y^2$ be the variance associated with (2) and $\sigma_{\overline{t^2}}^2=\sigma_x^2$ the variance associated with (3). Since the two variables in my function f come from the same set of data, when I propagate the error I write something like:

\begin{equation}
\sigma^2_f=\Bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Bigg)^2\sigma_x^2+\Bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigg)^2\sigma_y^2+2\Bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigg)\sigma_{x,y}\tag{4}
\end{equation}
where

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{x,y}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\overline{x})(y_i-\overline{y})\tag{5}
\end{equation}

In my case (4) is:

\begin{equation}
\sigma^2_f=\Big(1\Big)^2\sigma_{\overline{t^2}}^2+\Big(2\overline{t}\Big)^2\sigma_{\overline{t}}^2+2\Big(1\Big)\Big(-2\overline{t}\Big)\sigma_{\overline{t^2},\overline{t}}\tag{6}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\overline{t^2},\overline{t}}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(t_i^2-\overline{t^2})(t_i-\overline{t})\tag{7}
\end{equation}

is there something very wrong I'm not seeing?